# How to parse the Data part of the Oracle TNS protocol？

Tags: oracle, wireshark, tns

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbQXD.png)

The above picture is the Oracle TNS packet I captured with wireshark. How to parse the Data part?

Comment: A lot of people are properly reluctant to open links from strangers on the internet.  Noting prevents you from updating your question and posting the content as code-formatted text.

Comment: What do you mean by "parse"? If the data is not encrypted, then it is standard ASCII HEX values. If it is encrypted, then it isn't possible to do anything with it, really.

Comment: TNS is a proprietary protocol, so unless you have access to the protocol specification, it's going to be extremely difficult, if not impossible, to properly decipher the data.  On the other hand, if you do have access to the protocol specification, then you would need to modify the [Wireshark TNS dissector](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/blob/master/epan/dissectors/packet-tns.c) in order to support the dissection of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use NetData Lite, a free packet analyser that has been in continual development and evolution for as long as Wireshark and fully parses almost all types of TNS messages, handling up to 6 different dialects (integer formatting methods) in most versions from 308 to 318.  Its documentation explains why it is a far more powerful tool for diagnosing all types of performance problems. It can be downloaded from ftp://measureit.serveftp.net/ (user ID: NetDataLite; password: visual!ser)

Here is the NetData description of [the captured response message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdHIJ.png)